# How to pass args from html to js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass the value of an input this way:

html

```
<tr ng-controller="fCtrl as fiche">
    <td>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="q" ng-model="qo" >
            <input type="checkbox" name="q" ng-model="qa" >
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="fiche.submitEdit(q)">Modifier</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

js

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('m', [ ]);

    app.controller('fCtrl', function(){
        this.submitEdit = function(q){
             alert(q);
        }
    });

})();
```

But, doing that I can't catch anything. I've also tried using `fiche.submitEdit({{q}})`, but it wouldn't work. Any brilliant idea, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what are you expecting `q` to be? There is nothing in your markup or scope that matches it other than `name` on input's. Therefore it is undefined when you pass it as argument of your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using ng-model no need to pass the data, try it

```
<table ng-app="m">
<tr ng-controller="fCtrl">
<td>
    <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q" ng-model="qo" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="q" ng-model="qa" >
    </span>
</td>
<td>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitEdit()">Modifier</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
(function(){
var app = angular.module('m', [ ]);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.qo = "";
    $scope.submitEdit = function(){
         alert($scope.qo);
    }
});

})();
```

Comment: Doing that, I've got this error message `ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
    at submitEdition (http://localhost/dashboard/public/js/app.js:16:25)
    at http://localhost/dashboard/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:175:290
    at http://localhost/dashboard/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:192:357
    at k.$eval (http://localhost/dashboard/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:111:353)
    at k.$apply (http://localhost/dashboard/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:112:121)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/dashboard/ve`

Comment: Have you written ng-app="m" above the tr?

Comment: Or included $scope in your function arguments?

Comment: My code should work if your are using proper angular js library, for details you can check https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04

Comment: Hey, have you checked it whether it's running after adding ng-app like me, check y code.

Answer (score 0):

I have never working with controller aliases.
This should work?

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('m', [ ]);

app.controller('fCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.submitEdit = function(){
         alert($scope.qo);
    }
}]);

})();
```

And in html just call ng-click="submitEdit()"

Answer (score 0):

To start with , always use a dot in `ng-model`. It almost appears that is what you were wanting to do and that you would have one object `q` when you submit.

The powerful part of `ng-model` is it will create the scope objects if they don't already exist.

In your case if you changed the `ng-model`'s to `q.a` and `q.o` your method would work and you would have one object `q` in scope with properties `a` and `o` .

However you have also set up a **controller alias** so now you need to prefix all your html scope variables with that controller alias

```
<input type="checkbox" name="q" ng-model="fiche.q.o" >
<input type="checkbox" name="q" ng-model="fiche.q.a" >

<button ng-click="fiche.submitEdit(fiche.q)">


 $scope.submitEdit = function(q){
     alert($scope.q.o);
}
```

There really is no need to pass the object as argument since it already exists in scope as `$scope.q`